# Long Table Exceed \linewidth

Tags: longtable

I have some questions regarding specifying column width in `\longtable` using `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=0.6in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage {lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\usepackage{ ragged2e }
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{layouts}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}
        {
            p{0.1\textwidth}
            p{0.1\linewidth} 
            p{0.1\linewidth} 
            p{0.1\linewidth} 
            p{0.1\linewidth} 
            p{0.1\linewidth} 
            p{0.1\linewidth} 
            p{0.1\linewidth} 
            p{0.1\linewidth} 
            p{0.1\linewidth}
        }
        \hline
        a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a\\
        b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=0.6in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage {lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\usepackage{ ragged2e }
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{layouts}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{p{\linewidth}}
        \hline
        a\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus, what should i do to fit x columns by dividing \linewidth evenly in a page?

Note: I have to use `\longtable` as the table might span multiple pages and i am using TeXstudio to compile my code.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide code we can compile. Do you need the table to run to multiple pages?

Comment: yes, i will update the code snippet in a moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following simplified column specification

```
\begin{longtable}
  {
    *{10}{p{\dimexpr.1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
  }
```

Each `p`-column has the `\tabcolsep` gap removed from both sides - the main cause for your table not fitting within the page margins. Also see [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

An alternative would be to use [`ltxtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable) which merges the use of [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) with that of [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), allowing you to specify `X`-type columns that naturally stretch to fit the remainder of the pre-specified `longtable` width.

Comment: Hi Werner, thanks a lot for your suggestion, i will go with the simplified column specification for now as the ltxtable requires table definition to be in different file.

Comment: Hi Werner, if i change the column count , would it accommodate the column width automatically?

Comment: @vincent911001: No. Since you've used `10` columns, I specified the column width as 1/10 of `\linewidth`. If you have (say) 12 columns, then use `0.8333\linewidth` (or 1/12 of `\linewidth`).

Comment: Thanks Werner, i have tried that just now, now i am trying to dynamically adjust the column width by getting 1/(column count) * \linewidth. Is that possible in Latex? If not , then i will find my own ways of writing this out as i am generating this in my application.

Comment: @vincent911001: Sure. Add the [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) package to your preamble and then calculate the length: `\newlength{\mylen} \setlength{\mylen}{\linewidth / 12}`. Now you can use `*{12}{p{\dimexpr\mylen-2\tabcolsep}}`.

Comment: You don't need `\dimexpr` if you use `calc`.

Comment: @Werner, i am experiencing text overflowing in longtable when using `\newline`. Is it approriate for me to ask here or start another thread? Besides, is it possible to get the solution without switching to another tabular package?

Comment: @Werner, thanks alot for your help from another post which solves this problem using `\seqsplit`.
@Werner and @cfr, thanks alot guys.

Answer (score 4):

The width of the columns given by `p` does not take account of the space between the columns and at the left and right of the first and final entries respectively.

You can either calculate a value yourself or use one of the packages which combine the facilities of `tabularx` with those of `longtable`. Here's the former approach:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=0.6in,bottom=0.6in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable,calc,array}
\newlength\mycolwidth
\begin{document}
\noindent
\setlength\mycolwidth{.1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}%
\begin{longtable}{*{10}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\mycolwidth}}}
    \toprule
    apple & apple & apple & apple & apple & apple & apple& apple & apple & apple\\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: fitted columns]

## EDIT

Here's a way of calculating them automatically by using a custom `longtablex` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=0.6in,bottom=0.6in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable,calc,array}
\newlength\mycolwidth
\newenvironment{longtablex}[1][10]{%
  \noindent
  \setlength\mycolwidth{\linewidth/#1-2\tabcolsep}%
  \begin{longtable}{*{#1}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\mycolwidth}}}%
}{%
  \end{longtable}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtablex}
    \toprule
    apple & apple & apple & apple & apple & apple & apple& apple & apple & apple\\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtablex}

\begin{longtablex}[5]
    \toprule
    apple & apple & apple & apple & apple \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtablex}

\begin{longtablex}[3]
    \toprule
    apple & apple & apple  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtablex}
\end{document}
```

[image: variations]

Comment: Hi cfr, thanks a lot for your answer. Wish i could accept both answers.

Comment: @vincent911001 Please see edit.

Comment: thanks for the extendable solution from you. But, can i know what this mean `\newenvironment{longtablex}[1][10]{%
  \noindent
  \setlength\mycolwidth{\linewidth/#1-2\tabcolsep}%
  \begin{longtable}{*{#1}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\mycolwidth}}}%
}{%
  \end{longtable}%
}`

Comment: i kind of understand the snippet, but can i know what is the usage of second parameter `[10]`. Is it a default column count?

Comment: @vincent911001 It makes the single argument (`[1]`) optional by specifying the default, yes, as `[10]` for `10`. So it means the environment can be used with no argument (for 10 columns) or with an argument in square brackets, which should specify the number of columns i.e. be a positive integer. If I just had `[1]` the argument would be required and would, therefore, go in curly brackets.

Comment: @vincent911001 You can only ping one person at a time. If you'd pinged me in your comment on Werner's post, though, Werner would also get pinged as it is Werner's post. But if you explicitly ping Werner, I don't get pinged, too, it seems.

Comment: thanks for the tips, noted and thanks a lot for your elegant solution as i can write less code using yours solution.

Answer (score 2):

You also have the `ltablex` which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. Also, I replaced  the `\hline`s with rules from `booktabs`, to add some vertical padding around them:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in, vmargin=0.6in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltablex, booktabs}
\usepackage {lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\usepackage{ ragged2e }
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{layouts}
\keepXColumns

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{10}{X}}
         \toprule
        a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a\\
        b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your solution and your help. Will definitely try it out.